# RxJS socket.io reconnection with retryWhen()

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying to resubscribe to socket events when socket.io disconnects->reconnects using RxJS.

Below is a slimed down simplified version of what I have so far. I am wrapping socket.io with an Observable, which is wrapped by another Observable that filters all socket events. I want to use retryWhen after the socket reconnects and not sure how to accomplish this...

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
function socket() {
    return Observable.create(subscriber => {
        let socket = io('my_socket_path');
        let _onevent = socket.onevent;

        socket.onevent = (packet) => {
            subscriber.next(packet);
            _onevent.call(socket, packet);
        };

        socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
            subscriber.error(data);
        });

        return () => {
            socket.close();
        };
    }).share();
}
function getSocketEvent(event) {
    const socket = socket();
    return Observable.create(subscriber => {
        const eventSubscription = socket
            .filter(packet => packet.data[0] === event)
            .subscribe(packet => {
                subscriber.next(packet);
            });

        return () => {
            eventSubscription.unsubscribe();
        };
    }).share()
      .retryWhen(
       //Not sure how to trigger re-subscription here when socket reconnects
    ));
}
getSocketEvent('myGreatEvent').subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Thank-you

**Update:**

I noticed that the retryWhen() is called when I just pass the subscriber in the subscription of the socket like this:

```
...
 const eventSubscription = socket
        .filter(packet => packet.data[0] === event)
        .subscribe(subscriber); //now triggers retryWhen()...
...
```

Even with this new discovery, I am not sure why just passing subscriber triggers the retryWhen, and how to resubscribe when socket comes back online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a newbie, I found my issue and answering my own question in case it helps someone...

Turns out it was simple, I needed to pass down all handlers in the subscribe.

```
.subscribe(
   (packet) => subscriber.next(packet),
   (error) => subscriber.error(error),
   () => console.log('completed')
);
```